# What's wrong with the java code as the hashmap is storing key based on number of values

Tags: java, hashmap

Input is given as follows:-

```
2
3 2
piygu ezyfo rzotm
1 piygu
6 tefwz tefwz piygu ezyfo tefwz piygu
4 1
kssdy tjzhy ljzym kegqz
4 kegqz kegqz kegqz vxvyj
```

The first input is the number of test cases.Second-line has two integers(n & k).The first one(n) refers to the number of words. And second integer (k) refers to the next number of lines.
And then the next line contains n-words. And then their k lines. Each line has an integer(l) referring to the number of words in the same line. Problem is to print yes or no depending upon whether the words in the first line are available in other lines.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ForgottenLanguage {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    while(t-->0) {
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int k=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        HashMap<String,String> hashmap=new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            String a=sc.next();
            hashmap.put(a,"NO");
        }
        sc.nextLine();
        while(k-->0) {
            int l=sc.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
                String st=sc.next();
                if(hashmap.containsKey(st)) {
                    hashmap.put(st, "YES");
                }
            }
              
            for(String s:hashmap.keySet()) {
                System.out.print(hashmap.get(s)+" ");
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
}
```

I have implemented this code. And I am getting output as follows

```
YES NO NO YES YES NO 
NO NO YES NO
```

Instead of getting it as follows

YES YES NO

NO NO NO YES

Comment: And well, you add a lot of NO then YES strings into that map, and you print those. I think you should step back and rethink what you WANT to happen.

Comment: And then: please read that help about using markdown for formatting. The preview window told you that your content didnt look like you put it into the question. So: please spend the time required to format your input so that it is readable, and shows up the way you intend it to.

Comment: Finally: note that your "expected output" ... is just your INPUT. So: your question isnt clear.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat for the first line for each string i have to print yes or no so I added no for all of the strings in the first line by using this for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
   String a=sc.next();
   hashmap.put(a,"NO");
  }ButIi have to print yes only when the later lines contains words that are present in the first line.

Comment: @SiaSaxena And this was not obvious from your question. You talked about words being available, which could mean many things. Please reword your question to be more understandable. And I don't believe that any of these numbers were necessary if you used a better input object. I would have used a BufferedReader rather than Scanner.

Comment: Just wondering: is this homework, or what "underlying" problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @GhostCat This is more like the questions on https://www.hackerearth.com/. A lot of young programmers today practice on such websites. So no, I don't think this is a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Improvement:` `Map<String, String>` is quite difficult to maintain in this scenario. To I change it with `Map<String, Boolean>`.
2. `Correction:` To maintain actual order, use `LinkedHashMap`. The `HashMap` class does not maintain the `order` of the elements. That's why the last output was not as expected.
3. `Correction:` Instead of printing(`System.out`) inside `2nd loop`, print your data just after your `2nd while loop` is finished.

A modified version of your code:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForgottenLanguage {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int k = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            Map<String, Boolean> linkedHashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                String a = sc.next();
                linkedHashmap.put(a, false);
            }
            sc.nextLine();
            while (k-- > 0) {
                int l = sc.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    String st = sc.next();
                    if (linkedHashmap.containsKey(st)) {
                        linkedHashmap.put(st, true);
                    }
                }
                //remove printing logic from here
            }
            
            for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : linkedHashmap.entrySet())
            {
                if(entry.getValue()) {
                    System.out.print("YES" + " ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print("NO" + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

My console view(input-output):

```
2
3 2
piygu ezyfo rzotm
1 piygu
6 tefwz tefwz piygu ezyfo tefwz piygu
YES YES NO 
4 1
kssdy tjzhy ljzym kegqz
4 kegqz kegqz kegqz vxvyj
NO NO NO YES
```